# Who are the possible models for Munch's Puberty?

Tags: art, norway, painting

***[Puberty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puberty_(Munch_painting))*** by the Norwegian painter **Edvard Munch** is certainly the most uncomfortable viewing experience I've ever had in the realm of fine art. There's also a kind of psychological complexity to it, and, in spite of myself, it's a painting I find myself coming back to every couple of years.

I was curious about **the identity of the model**. All the articles I could find through Google just said that there was a great deal of interesting speculation about her, but nothing was ever established beyond doubt. But because of the detail around her collarbones, it is likely Munch used a live model.

I think I can remember reading, a few years ago, one theory that the model was Munch's landlord's daughter, and another theory that she was Munch's younger sister. (I couldn't find anything to back up either of these theories when I searched just now.) Does anyone have anything more solid in this regard?

Comment: Is this really a *history* question?

Comment: Can you please edit the question to include the details and links for some of the articles you've found so far?

Comment: I saw a Munch exhibition at San Francisco's MoMA that had a lot of background on the models, but honestly I have forgotten most of it other than the general feeling that Munch treated the women in his life (some of whom were his primary models) terribly.

Comment: @kimchilover Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: @Joachim Not all fact questions about past events are history questions.

Comment: @kimchilover That's not really an answer to my question (sorry, I'm genuinely interested and trying not to be pedantic): then how is this fact question not a history question?